# Transferring Ultimate Marvel vs Capcom 3 from Vita to PS3

Tags: ps3, ps-vita, ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3

I purchased Ultimate Marvel vs Capcom 3 from the PSN for the PS Vita. I've read that I can access DLC stuff for this game from either the Vita or my PS3. What I was wondering is, can I also transfer the entire game to be played on my PS3 or do I need to buy a separate copy of the game itself for the PS3?

Answer (score 2):

No. These are two different games and require separate purchases.

While some cross platform PSN games give you versions of the game for both platforms when you purchase them (for example, *MotorStorm RC* and the future release of *When Vikings Attack*), this is not the case for UMvC3.